# R - Caret train() "Error: Stopping" with "Not all variable names used in object found in newdata"

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, naivebayes

I am trying to build a simple [Naive Bayes classifer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) for [mushroom data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data). I want to use all of the variables as categorical predictors to predict if a mushroom is edible.

I am using [caret](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.html) package.

Here is my code in full:

```
##################################################################################
# Prepare R and R Studio environment
##################################################################################

# Clear the R studio console
cat("\014")

# Remove objects from environment
rm(list = ls())

# Install and load packages if necessary
if (!require(tidyverse)) {
  install.packages("tidyverse")
  library(tidyverse)
}
if (!require(caret)) {
  install.packages("caret")
  library(caret)
}
if (!require(klaR)) {
  install.packages("klaR")
  library(klaR)
}

#################################

mushrooms <- read.csv("agaricus-lepiota.data", stringsAsFactors = TRUE, header = FALSE)

na.omit(mushrooms)

names(mushrooms) <- c("edibility", "capShape", "capSurface", "cap-color", "bruises", "odor", "gill-attachment", "gill-spacing", "gill-size", "gill-color", "stalk-shape", "stalk-root", "stalk-surface-above-ring", "stalk-surface-below-ring", "stalk-color-above-ring", "stalk-color-below-ring", "veil-type", "veil-color", "ring-number", "ring-type", "spore-print-color", "population", "habitat")

# convert bruises to a logical variable
mushrooms$bruises <- mushrooms$bruises == 't'

set.seed(1234)
split <- createDataPartition(mushrooms$edibility, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)

train <- mushrooms[split, ]
test <- mushrooms[-split, ]

predictors <- names(train)[2:20] #Create response and predictor data

x <- train[,predictors] #predictors
y <- train$edibility #response

train_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 1) # Set up 1 fold cross validation

edibility_mod1 <- train( #train the model
  x = x,
  y = y,
  method = "nb", 
  trControl = train_control
)
```

When executing the train() function I get the following output:

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :2     NA's   :2    
Error: Stopping
In addition: Warning messages:
1: predictions failed for Fold1: usekernel= TRUE, fL=0, adjust=1 Error in predict.NaiveBayes(modelFit, newdata) : 
  Not all variable names used in object found in newdata
 
2: model fit failed for Fold1: usekernel=FALSE, fL=0, adjust=1 Error in x[, 2] : subscript out of bounds
 
3: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

x and y after script run:

```
> str(x)
'data.frame':   6500 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ capShape                : Factor w/ 6 levels "b","c","f","k",..: 6 6 1 6 6 6 1 1 6 1 ...
 $ capSurface              : Factor w/ 4 levels "f","g","s","y": 3 3 3 4 3 4 3 4 4 3 ...
 $ cap-color               : Factor w/ 10 levels "b","c","e","g",..: 5 10 9 9 4 10 9 9 9 10 ...
 $ bruises                 : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
 $ odor                    : Factor w/ 9 levels "a","c","f","l",..: 7 1 4 7 6 1 1 4 7 1 ...
 $ gill-attachment         : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","f": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ gill-spacing            : Factor w/ 2 levels "c","w": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ gill-size               : Factor w/ 2 levels "b","n": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ gill-color              : Factor w/ 12 levels "b","e","g","h",..: 5 5 6 6 5 6 3 6 8 3 ...
 $ stalk-shape             : Factor w/ 2 levels "e","t": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ stalk-root              : Factor w/ 5 levels "?","b","c","e",..: 4 3 3 4 4 3 3 3 4 3 ...
 $ stalk-surface-above-ring: Factor w/ 4 levels "f","k","s","y": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ stalk-surface-below-ring: Factor w/ 4 levels "f","k","s","y": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ stalk-color-above-ring  : Factor w/ 9 levels "b","c","e","g",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ stalk-color-below-ring  : Factor w/ 9 levels "b","c","e","g",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ veil-type               : Factor w/ 1 level "p": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ veil-color              : Factor w/ 4 levels "n","o","w","y": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ ring-number             : Factor w/ 3 levels "n","o","t": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ ring-type               : Factor w/ 5 levels "e","f","l","n",..: 5 5 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 5 ...



> str(y)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "e","p": 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
```

My environment is:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0     
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin17.0                  
system         x86_64, darwin17.0          
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10                          
day            10                          
svn rev        79318                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out     
> RStudio.Version()
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2020). RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R. RStudio, PBC, Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, PBC},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2020},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.3.1093’

$release_name
[1] "Apricot Nasturtium"
```

Comment: possibly class imbalance of the target variable is the problem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192884/naive-bayes-error-with-caret

Comment: also not sure if the target variable needs to be factor? you are reading it in as text it appears....

Comment: Wouldn't I get a more explicit error for class imbalance. Will look into it anyway.

Comment: y is factor, updating the question with output to show that if it helps.

Comment: x and y output in edited question shows all x variables are factors except for one logical. I will check on NA, good idea.

Comment: Not sure the TRUE/FALSE works as a target variable: try 0 and 1 as an explicite factor (and clean possible NAs)

Comment: Target value is not TRUE/FALSE, one of the predictors is.

Comment: Added in na.omit(mushrooms) to remove NA's, I don't think there were any.

Comment: I just tried the h2o::h2o.naiveBayes() and it works... though I can not make it work in caret ;(

Comment: When you send a factor into caret it auto-magically converts that factor into a `one-hot` or `dummy` encoded variable as needed. So you get one column for each level of the factor. However, if you have imbalanced data in the training or test set it might not have any data for that new column so you get a warning message telling you not all variable names were used (aka: not all factor values were used).

Comment: One way to make that warning go away is to use other function to pre-convert your data frame to a one-hot/dummy encoded data set before passing it into your training function and imputing (with 0) any missing columns. However, if you have 0 data in any features you should probably do some feature engineering to deal with them somehow.

Comment: I tried to test the idea from @AdamSampson by using 100% of my data as the training data, in this way I thought I should be able to remove the possibility of having columns with no data. I still get the same error & warnings. My code change to do this was to change "p = 0.8" to "p = 1" in the source code above.

Comment: Yeah. I wouldn't suggest using all the data this way, but I suppose it's a good way to see if that was the problem. Looks like NB just isn't using all the data for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a bit tricky, most naive bayes implementation or at least the one you are using (from kLAR which is derived from e1071) uses a normal distribution. You can see under the details of [naiveBayes help page from e1071](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-3/topics/naiveBayes):

> The standard naive Bayes classifier (at least this implementation)
> assumes independence of the predictor variables, and Gaussian
> distribution (given the target class) of metric predictors. For
> attributes with missing values, the corresponding table entries are
> omitted for prediction.

And your predictors are categorical so this might be problematic. You can try to set `kernel=TRUE` and `adjust=1` to force it towards normal, and avoid `kernel=FALSE` which will throw the error.

Before that we remove columns with only 1 level and sort out the column names, also in this case it's easier to use the formula and avoid the making dummy variables :

```
df = train 
levels(df[["veil-type"]])
[1] "p"
df[["veil-type"]]=NULL
colnames(df) = gsub("-","_",colnames(df))

Grid = expand.grid(usekernel=TRUE,adjust=1,fL=c(0.2,0.5,0.8))

mod1 <- train(edibility~.,data=df,
  method = "nb", trControl = trainControl(method="cv",number=5),
  tuneGrid=Grid
)

 mod1
Naive Bayes 

6500 samples
  21 predictor
   2 classes: 'e', 'p' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 5200, 5200, 5200, 5200, 5200 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  fL   Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.2  0.9243077  0.8478624
  0.5  0.9243077  0.8478624
  0.8  0.9243077  0.8478624

Tuning parameter 'usekernel' was held constant at a value of TRUE

Tuning parameter 'adjust' was held constant at a value of 1
Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were fL = 0.2, usekernel = TRUE and
 adjust = 1.
```

Comment: If my predictors are non-metric, i.e. categorical/nominal/factors, why would the NB algorithm need to use a gaussian distribution or a non-parametric kernel technique. I am new to this so please let me know what I am missing here. I am now trying to use multinomial_naive_bayes() function instead, I think it may suit me better, but I can't figure out how to do my post processing see question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819019/r-generate-confusion-matrix-and-roc-for-model-generated-by-multinomial-naive-b

Comment: The model needs to evaluate the conditional probability of the observation given the predictor, and most of them assumes that your predictor is gaussian. you can see https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_naive_bayes_1.html#continuous-variables . In the rest of this blog, it explains how the mutlinomial would work

Answer (score 1):

instead of using "nb" in the train function. use "naive_bayes". it worked for me even with severe class imbalance problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kurati! can you please expand this answer to describe the different implementations and why this one works?