# R - Generate confusion matrix and ROC for model generated by multinomial_naive_bayes() function

Tags: r, r-caret, naivebayes

I have a data set with many factor/categorical/nominal columns/variables/features. I need to create a multinomial naive bayes classifier for this data. I tried using the caret library but I don't think that was doing a multinomial naive bayes, I think it was doing gaussian naive bayes, details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64757800/r-caret-train-error-stopping-with-not-all-variable-names-used-in-object). I have now discovered multinomial_naive_bayes() which seems to be perfect. It seems to handle nulls in the predictor variables and a variable with only 1 value without complaining.

The issue is, I can't figure out how to do my "post processing/analysis" of the model generated by the multinomial_naive_bayes() function. I want to get a caret style confusionMatrix on the model and also on the prediction output vs the test data to assess the classifier. I would also like to generate a ROC curve. How can I do this?

I have included the sample/reference/example from the documentation of multinomial_naive_bayes() below, how would I update this code to get my confusionMatricies and ROC curve.

From: R Package '[naivebayes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naivebayes/naivebayes.pdf)', section: **multinomial_naive_bayes** pg 10

```
library(naivebayes)

### Simulate the data:
cols <- 10 ; rows <- 100
M <- matrix(sample(0:5, rows * cols, TRUE, prob = c(0.95, rep(0.01, 5))), nrow = rows, ncol = cols)
y <- factor(sample(paste0("class", LETTERS[1:2]), rows, TRUE, prob = c(0.3,0.7)))
colnames(M) <- paste0("V", seq_len(ncol(M)))
laplace <- 1

### Train the Multinomial Naive Bayes
mnb <- multinomial_naive_bayes(x = M, y = y, laplace = laplace)
summary(mnb)
    
# Classification
head(predict(mnb, newdata = M, type = "class")) # head(mnb %class% M)

# Posterior probabilities
head(predict(mnb, newdata = M, type = "prob")) # head(mnb %prob% M)

# Parameter estimates
coef(mnb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the caret function confusionMatrix:

```
library(caret)
pred = predict(mnb, newdata = M, type = "class")
confusionMatrix(table(pred,y))

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

        y
pred     classA classB
  classA     10      3
  classB     20     67
```

Or if the factor levels are the same:

```
confusionMatrix(pred,y)
```

For ROC curve, you need to provide the probability of the prediction:

```
library(pROC)
roc_ = roc(y,predict(mnb, newdata = M, type ="prob")[,2])

plot(roc_)
```

[image]